# Sorting 3 columns and getting the average

Tags: linux, bash, unix

when I run my testing.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE=$1
COUNT=0
while read -r SID FIRST LAST S1 S2 S3 
do
    SUM=$(expr $S1 + $S2 + $S3)
    AVG=$(expr $SUM / 3)
    printf '%d [%d] %s, %s\n' "$AVG" "$SID" "$LAST" "$FIRST"
done < "$FILE" | sort -k 3,3n -k 4,4n -k 2,2g
```

I get the following errors.

```
expr: non-integer argument

expr: syntax error
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I also tried echo, awk, and bc but I got similar errors for all of them.

I run the file like this:

/testing.sh /home/user/Desktop/sample.txt

This is the sample text.

```
123456789 Lee Johnson 72 85 90
999999999 Jaime Smith 90 92 91
888111818 JC Forney 100 81 97
290010111 Terry Lee 100 99 100
199144454 Tracey Camp 77 84 84
299226663 Laney Camp 70 74 71
434401929 Skyler Camp 78 81 82
928441032 Jess Forester 85 80 82
928441032 Chris Forester 97 94 89
```

When I run my program, this should be the output:

```
71 [299226663] Camp, Laney
80 [434401929] Camp, Skyler
81 [199144454] Camp, Tracey
93 [928441032] Forester, Chris
82 [928441032] Forester, Jess
92 [888111818] Forney, JC
82 [123456789] Johnson, Lee
99 [290010111] Lee, Terry
91 [999999999] Smith, Jaime
```

Comment: works fine here with your data. Can you output $S1, $S2, $S3 ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre when I output them by themselves I get. invalid numberne 6: printf: 90 for the numbers in the last column (the 90 changes for the values of each row).

Comment: if your any of your files have passed thru the MS Windows environment, confirm they have `\r\n` line endings by using `cat -vet myScript.sh myData.txt`. If you see `^M$` at the end of line, you have `\r\n` lineendings. Use `dos2unix myScript.sh myData.txt` to clean them  up. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I'm using linux

Comment: problems as you describe are often the result of MS Windows data  (or scripts). Just wanted to eliminate that as a possible problem. Good luck.

Comment: but try using `SUM=$(( $S1 + $S2 + $S3 ))` etc. Good luck.

Comment: You probably have non conforming field.  Comment out the sort part and it will probably be obvious.

Comment: able to replicate the issue if input file is dos format as others have pointed out.. you might have a program `dos2unix` which can help you change to unix style line ending.. or use `perl -i -pe 's|\r\n|\n|' /home/user/Desktop/sample.txt`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `S3` does not actually contain a value such as `90`, but instead contains values such as `90$'\r'`, because your input file has CRLF (DOS) rather than LF (UNIX) newlines. This most often happens if you got your input file from a non-UNIX system.

Fix the file, using tools such as `dos2unix` or the vim command `:set fileformat=unix`, or use code akin to the following in your script:

```
S3=${S3%$'\r'} # remove any trailing $'\r' from S3
```

Comment: Add '*clairvoyant*' as one of @Charles many talents. Way to read between the lines (no pun intended`:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, thank you, but it's sp asic and shellter who got to the diagnosis first -- I just wrote up an answer encapsulating it.